# Alamofire include App archive Validation failed

Tags: iphone, ios7, swift, ios8, alamofire

I have been trying to submit my swift app to appstore and i'm facing this error. This is my first time using alamofire. The app worked fine during debbuging in ios8 and ios7. But i'm not able to submit it to appstore. Can anyone guide me with what i'm doing wrong?

[image: Alamofire App Archive Validation Failed]

Answer (score 1):

dynamic code execution is ios8 only. so no embedded frameworks for is

alamofire has a documented workaround though:

> For application targets that do not support embedded frameworks, such as iOS 7, Alamofire can be integrated by including the `Alamofire.swift` source file directly, wrapping the top-level types in `struct Alamofire` to simulate a namespace. Yes, this sucks.

So: Copy The file into Your project and ignore the framework. Then edit the file and add `struct Alamofire {` ... The original content ... and a `}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try it. Is there something that i can refer for the same like a sample?

Comment: Is there any more info you can give on this approach?